# pd.to_datetime error ValueError: '-' is a bad directive

Tags: pandas, datetime

Hi I am trying to convert `26-01-2019 16:04:04.85`

the code I am using is `pd.to_datetime(time, format="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%-s")`

output is `ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%-s'`

is the space or the hyphens throwing this off?

Answer (score 1):

Change format `%H` for hours and `%f` for microseconds, check also http://strftime.org/:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['26-01-2019 16:04:04.85','26-01-2019 16:04:04.8']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
print (df)
                     date
0 2019-01-26 16:04:04.850
1 2019-01-26 16:04:04.800

print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```